# How to setup Spring backend with JWT and Kubernetes

Tags: spring, docker, kubernetes, jwt, microservices

I implemented a Spring backend which is responsible to store different data (users, lectures, ...). This backend is secured with a JWT and everything is working fine. For my studies I want to enhance the backend and now I want to use a microservice architecture instead of a monolith. For this purpose I have the requirements to use Docker and Kubernetes. I always read articles which write that I need a Authorization Server and a Ressource Server when I want to use the JWT in a microservice architecture. Is that correct? And do I need a Gateway (e.g. Zuul) for my purpose? Can someone help me to structure the project and give advice for the technology stack. At the end the whole project will run in one single server.

I implemented a molotithical backend, secured with JWT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes officially supports [authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#openid-connect-tokens) to API server within JSON Web Tokens(JWT) through [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/) tool using OAuth 2.0 protocol for user request identification. However, this only represents a part of [Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#authorization-modules) model, which determines how authenticated user can be granted with appropriate security policies or roles to manage Kubernetes cluster resources.

In order to build or migrate application to Kubernetes, you might consider to expose application outside the cluster, for that purpose [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) proxies requests to exact service by matching request path. Actually, `Ingress` is a logical resource element which describes a set of rules for traffic management via [Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/). Therefore, Ingress controller can play a role of API Gateway by delivering L7 network facilities like: load balancing, SSL termination and HTTP/HTTPS traffic routing for nested application services.

As you mentioned [Zuul](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul) gateway can be one of the option for the edge proxying service in front of Kubernetes cluster, however I would recommend to look for some more Kubernetes oriented solutions. [Istio](https://istio.io/) is a good example, as it brings a wide set of network router functions with a quite simple integration into Kubernetes cluster via its core [Service mesh](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/#what-is-a-service-mesh) design. Istio provides end user authentication via JWT within declared authentication [policy](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authn-policy/#end-user-authentication).

Alternativelly, you can get through [Nginx plus](https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx/) features with announced JWT authentication as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! But it is such a complex topic. As you mentioned the Backend could look like this: Spring Boot for each Microservice. Every microservice (lecture-service, ...) will then be containerized with Docker and Kubernetes will handle the cluster. As a gateway I will use Ingress. For the communication between the microservices I can use Ribbon or RestTemplate (Is this correct?). And for the security I can use OpenID Connect or Istio. Both working with jwt. Is this a good technology stack for a solid microservice architecture and do I consider everyhting which is necessary?

Comment: Communication between different services within the same Kubernetes cluster is organized through CNI network [plugins](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network), Ingress can be replaced by Istio `istio-ingressgateway`.